# Best suited Data structure in redis for value for maintaining user profile

Tags: redis

I am using redis and looking for a data structure that's best suited for maintaining a user profile. The user profile contains String uid,long timestamp, int count1, String info1, String info2, String[5] lastest5activies.

One way could be to serialize a java object and store the string as value and second is to store it in JSON format. But since we have to keep this profile updated in realtime for some 50 million and above users(getting tens/hundreds of thousand transaction per second), parsing and editing the json object could be an overkill for each transaction.
And the saving java Object doesn't seem to be a popular way of storing value(not sure why), according to some posts I have read.

Could anyone please let me know the better approach, response time & memory wise?

Answer (score 0):

The hash data type is probably best suited for your needs. The default Redis settings will encode the data using the memory-efficient ziplist and you'll be able to update discrete fields.